# SCP set permissions or timestamps even for user in the same group

Tags: permissions, ssh, filesystem, scp

I am not the owner but in the same group as a file. The file has `-rw-rw-r--` permissions, and:

```
beet ~> umask -S
u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx
```

Over WinSCP, I am able to update the file but it produces this error:

> error occurred while setting permissions and/or timestamp

Why is this happening and is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting WinSCP documentation for the [error message](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_preserve_time_perm):

> You get this error, when a server fails to update file timestamp or permissions for some reason:
>
> - On some systems (e.g. Linux), **you need to be an owner of the file** (write permissions are not enough) **to modify its permissions or timestamp** (you will see an error like “Permissions denied” in error details).
>
> ...
>
> Whatever the reason is, you need to turn off [*Set permissions*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom#upload) and [*Preserve timestamp options*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom#common) or turn on [*Ignore permission errors*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom#upload).

Comment: I am aware of this. Is Ubuntu a Linux that permits owner only to modify timestamp?

Comment: I believe that all Linux systems do.